# The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)

Tags: android, android-adapterview

The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long)

Why i get this message when i tried to build the tutorial

```
package Fedail.Hello.Layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class Layout_Feras extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, Long id){
          Toast.makeText(Layout_Feras.this,"" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
        }
        );
    } 
}
```

Comment: if you get this error while following the Sams Android book, try just adding `import android.view.*;` on the top! It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Change this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, Long id)
```

to this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

When overriding a super method you will have to make sure all datatypes match the original types.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `Long` to `long` in `onItemClick()` and see if that helps.